# Struggling with WDS and UEFI/BIOS Bootissue

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2016, dhcp-server, wds

**Scenario:** We have following setup.

- Windows 2008 R2 - Active Directory Server with DHCP/DNS Roles (SRV01)
- Windows 2016 x64 STD GUI - WSUS  (SRV02) for deployment of windows updates to clients
- Windows 2016 x64 STD GUI - WDS (SRV03) with W2016 BOOT image, it also contains - Windows 7/10 images for network base windows installation
- We have 150 users with Windows 7 & 10 installed on different new / old hardware.

**Problem:**

We use WDS to deploy windows over the network.

- on Legacy BIOS users, when I dont use DCHP option 67, normal bios users can boot fine, but UEFI users get error

**>>>Starting PXE over IPv4.
PXE-E16: No Offer received.**

- on UEFI enabled users, When I enable DHCP Option 67 & point to file boot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi, then UEFI users can boot fine, but BIOS users gets error.

**PXE--E79: NBP is too big to fit in free base memory**

IS there any way both users can boot fine without adding/removal of option 67 ?